# find a function such...

Tags: calculus

> exercise :
>    A function $f$, continuous on the positive real axis, has the property that
>   $$\int_{1}^{xy}f(t)dt =y\int_{1}^{x}f(t)dt +x\int_{1}^{y}f(t)dt$$
>   for all $x > 0$ and all $y > 0$. If $f (1) = 3$, compute $f (x)$ for each $x > 0$.

My progress: I derive $f(xy)y = yf(x)+\int_{1}^{y}f(t)dt$ then $x=1$
$$f(y)y=3y+\int_{1}^{y}f(t)dt$$ then don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3):

Derive once more to get $$f'(y)y+f(y)=3+f(y)$$ then you have (changing from $y$ to $x$)
$$f'(x)x=3$$
$$f'(x)=\frac3x$$
$$f(x)=\int \frac3x\,dx = 3\ln(x)+C,\quad \text{for } x>0$$
Then you can find $C$:
$$f(1)=3\implies 3\ln(1)+C=3\implies C=3$$
$$f(x)=3\ln(x)+3$$

Comment: Thanks. I thought that if I kept deriving left me a differential equation.

Comment: @Elll actually, it is a differential equation, but a simple one :)